# two cron jobs - one after one not working well

Tags: cron, cpanel

This is my cron command:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null https://example.com/file1.php; wget -q -O - https://example.com/file2.php
```

The first file is running for 4 minutes for updating database (i have logs), the second file for some reason runs after 1:45, how it runs without the first one finished?

Thanks!

Comment: this doesnt look like the full cron command?

Comment: Why not? what missing?

Comment: You didnt post the timings of your cron

Comment: I'm using cpanel for this, i guess it doens't matter what time it's running..

Comment: Hey, someone knows?

Comment: Are you trying to run the 2nd command only when the 1st command has finished running?!

Comment: yes my friend..

Comment: anyone knows why?